# Diagram connection: 2 relationships between entities

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

My professor is telling me to have 2 relationships between my employee and department entities, one for the employee relationship and the other for the manager relationship (a manager is also an employee). What attributes do I connect them on? Do I need another primary/foreign key?

I intend making manager id a primary key in the department table, but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the departmentId has to be the primary key so that you don't have duplicate departments. If that's true, then in the Employee table, I would have one relationship from Employee.Department_ID to Department.Department_ID to define which department the employee belongs to. Then I would have a second relationship from Employee.Employee_ID to Department.Manager_ID which defines which employee is the department manager.

Comment: Thank you! Will that still work if the employee id and manager id are separate numbers? For example, a manager has two separate employee id's and manager id's